# Display items in PropertyGrid in the sequence they are declared

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

Is it possible to display PropertyGrid items in the UI in the way they are declared? I found that they are sorted first by CategoryAttribute and then by DisplayName attribute in ascending order.

I'm using .NET version 3.5 using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

EDIT

The application is a WPF application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I customize category sorting on a PropertyGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823327/how-can-i-customize-category-sorting-on-a-propertygrid)

Comment: Note that *strictly speaking* there is no mechanism of guaranteeing declaration order; see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) "The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies." - and note that `TypeDescriptor` (which is used by `PropertyGrid`) can only provide what is available to it. If order isn't guaranteed, then *order isn't guaranteed*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertysort

if you set the property `PropertySort` to  `PropertySort.NoSort` the sorting order of properties should follow this criterium: *Properties are displayed in the order in which they are retrieved from the TypeDescriptor.*

Comment: sorry, i should've mentioned that i'm working on a WPF application. i can't access System.Windows.Forms.PropertySort!

Comment: Then I guess you'd have to roll your own, as per this link: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2008/01/27/sorting-and-grouping-in-the-wpf-property-grid/

Comment: I found that this also works rather than NoSort.
    propGrid.PropertySort = PropertySort.Categorized;

Comment: User .NoSort result in losing category, use categorized instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can set quite a few properties using annotations, one of them is the "order of display"
using the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display Attribute would look like this:

```
[DisplayName("Error"),Display(Order = 5)]
public string Error { get; internal set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
private void propertyGrid1_PropertySortChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (propertyGrid1.PropertySort == PropertySort.CategorizedAlphabetical)
    {
        propertyGrid1.PropertySort = PropertySort.Categorized;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As above `[System.Windows.Forms.PropertySort]::NoSort`
However note if you are creating your control with a -Property parameter and setting both this PropertySort and the SelectedObject in that parameter's hashtable then it may still have the first item alphabetically as the SelectedGridItem and the grid scrolled to show that.

To ensure the new (original order's first) property is the SelectedGridItem either:
- `set the SelectedObject after the control is created`
- or for your control } you can use:
`}.SelectedGridItem = }.SelectedGridItem.ParentGridEntry.Children[0]`